# Calculate the statistical significance of survey questions

Tags: statistical-significance, survey

I have a question: How are you ? and two possible answers: Good and Bad.
If for example I got  over 30 questions ,10 Good answers and  20 Bad answers, which methods I should use to check if the difference between  the Bad answers and the Good answers is statistical significance.

Thank you.

Comment: An exact binomial test of $H_0: p = 1/2$ against $H_1: p \ne 1/2,$ where $p = P\{\text{Good}\},$ gives P-value about 10%. Getting a 10:20 split of Good:Bad is not unusual with only $n = 30$ observations. // If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=30,\,p=1/2),$ then the "expected" result is $E(X) = np = 15$ and the P-value of the test is $P(X \le 10) + P(X \ge 20) = 0.0987.$ In R statistical software, code `2*pbinom(10, 30, .5)` returns `0.09873715`.

Answer (score 0):

In statistical inference, we have various hypotheses which state variable associations/dependance etc and for accepting or rejecting hypothesis we perform various tests ( like t-test etc ) that calculate various metrics/numbers based on some pre-defined formulae and assumptions.

Now in your case, I believe since you haven't stated any hypothesis what you can do is look at confidence intervals for Binomial Distribution. Since your question has only 2 responses hence the Random Variable X = 0 being "Good" & X = 1 being "Bad" follows a Binomial Distribution.

Based on how much confident( aka notion of sureness ) you want to be you can get the confidence intervals and see the variation in the proportion of Good & Bad answer. That's one way to consider how good your proportions are.

However, if I can go a little bit forward, you can do the proportion test on either "Good"/"Bad" Responses. If I had to state the Null Hypothesis it will be that equal people respond Good/Bad and would check whether the difference in proportion is enough to draw inferences - like rejecting the Null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I do it with chi square/t-test/z-test ? What do you suggests ?

Comment: You can use proportion test here ( just a variant of the tests you mentioned above ) https://stattrek.com/hypothesis-test/proportion.aspx. Have a look at it .